# Cannot link Lua using conan's package manager despite the other conan packages working

Tags: c++, c, cmake, lua, conan

Edit: Solution at bottom

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(game)

set(SOURCES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
)


# Conan Requirements
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(game ${SOURCES})

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(sol2 REQUIRED)

target_compile_options( game PRIVATE 
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:
        -fsanitize=address,leak
    >
)

target_link_options( game PRIVATE 
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:
        -fsanitize=address,leak
    >
)

target_compile_features(game
    PRIVATE
        cxx_std_20
)

target_link_libraries(game PRIVATE 
    SDL2::SDL2
    sol2::sol
)
```

Here is my `conanfile.txt`

```
[requires]
lua/5.4.4
sdl/2.0.20

[generators]
cmake
cmake_find_package
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findsol2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "sol2", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sol2" with any of
  the following names:

    sol2Config.cmake
    sol2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "sol2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "sol2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "sol2"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I am building using the following methods:

```
conan install . --install-folder build --build=missing
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build/conan_toolchain.cmake -S . -B build -GNinja
cmake --build build
```

It's odd because I'm only getting the error about `sol2` and not `SDL`

edit: SOLUTION IS:

`CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(game)

set(SOURCES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
)


# Conan Requirements
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(game ${SOURCES})

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(sol2 REQUIRED)

target_compile_options( game PRIVATE 
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:
        -fsanitize=address,leak
    >
)

target_link_options( game PRIVATE 
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:
        -fsanitize=address,leak
    >
)

target_compile_features(game
    PRIVATE
        cxx_std_20
)

target_link_libraries(game PRIVATE 
    SDL2::SDL2
    sol2::sol2
)
```

`conanfile.txt` is

```
[requires]
sol2/3.3.0
sdl/2.0.20

[generators]
cmake
cmake_find_package
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

build script is

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

conan install . --install-folder build --build=missing
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build/conan_toolchain.cmake -S . -B build -GNinja
```

Comment: You forgot to say to CMake to find and link Lua to your project. Need to add `find_package(lua REQUIRED)` after `conan_basic_setup`, then after `add_executable` need to add `target_link_libraries(game PRIVATE lua::lua)`. Also, both `include` and `conan_basic_setup` come first, before `add_executable`. They set all stuff related to compiler, options and folder paths.

Comment: @uilianries I added what you said and I still get an error. I did a complete overhaul of the question so that it accurately reflects the post. I also switched from `lua` to `sol2`

Comment: Try with `cmake_find_package_multi` generator, it will generate solConfig.cmake file. Otherwise, you need to check CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, because cmake can't find those generated cmake files, even if they are there.